# Using shortened URL as public URL for Bluemix sites

Tags: ibm-cloud, google-crawlers, url-shortener

I have a site hosted on IBM Bluemix platform (using Liberty buildpack).  I'm using a URL shortening service to redirect so I wouldn't have to worry about the Bluemix URL changing in the future.  I would like to publicize that shortened URL, however Google crawler will only pickup and display the Bluemix URL for my site.  I searched around, seems the best way to handle this is to setup a 301 redirect so Google will display the "new" aka shortened URL.  However, I've not been able to find instructions on how to setup 301 redirects on Bluemix, or if it's even possible.  Does anyone know how? or maybe other suggestions on how to deal with Google crawlers in such an scenario.  Thanks!

Comment: How about assigning your own domain to your Bluemix app and have that picked up for search engines?

Comment: @data_henrik if this was my personal site, that's what I would have done. Unfortunately, this is not my own, I'm working with restraints here and need an alternate approach for this.